# Two column text with an image in top middle in HTML/CSS/PHP

Tags: html, css

I have a two column (table based) PHP generated HTML page.
I need to add an image & a title under it in it's top middle like this:
[image]

How can I achive this using html css ( & maybe php if needed) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this ALA article is pretty old, but it seems particularly fit to your case..
[Cross-Column Pull-Outs](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/)
Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try a CSS trick as shown on (of all places) [csstricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/). It seems to do exactly what you want.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/250" id="logo" />
    <div id="l">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies 
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit 
        amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum 
        sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt 
        condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. 
        Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, 
        neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna 
        eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan 
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies 
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit 
        amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum 
        sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt 
        condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. 
        Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, 
        neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna 
        eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan 
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
    <div id="r">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies 
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit 
        amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum 
        sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt 
        condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. 
        Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, 
        neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna 
        eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan 
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies 
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
        Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit 
        amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum 
        sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt 
        condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. 
        Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, 
        neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna 
        eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan 
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
}
#l, #r {
    width: 49%;
}
#l {
    float: left;
}
#r {
    float: right;
}
#l:before, #r:before {
    content: "";
    width: 125px;
    height: 250px;
}
#l:before {
    float: right;
}
#r:before {
    float: left;
}
```